# Pandas joining dataframes with different index levels/datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have two DataFrames which look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|      | dineType | menuName | unique | columns |
-------------------------------------------------
| date |          |          |        |         |
-------------------------------------------------
|%y%m%d|          |          |        |         |
-------------------------------------------------
...


-------------------------------------------------
|   | dineDate | dineType | menuName |         |
-------------------------------------------------
| 0 |  %Y%m%d  |          |          |         |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1 |          |          |          |         |
-------------------------------------------------
...
```

I want to join the two dataframes into one output. As you can see, the main problem is that the indexes from each table are different from each other. I want the output to follow the second table's format. Also the dates which each table starts from are different. 
How would I join these two dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging), it says you can use `left_on`, `right_on` and `left_index`, `right_index` attributes for joining based on columns and index in data frame.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_on='dineDate')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `string` with specific format for dates, you can use `pd.datetime` type; after converting `date` and `dineDate` column to `pd.datetime` type, joining task will work without additional work. You can do that, assuming data comes from CSV file, `parse_dates` option of `pd.read_csv`. For formatting output, you can set option `date_format='%Y%m%d' of`pd.DataFrame.to_csv`.

Please provide sample code if you need more details.