# KeyError: "['avg_sparsity_int'] not in index" while merging two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge three dataframes and my code does merge two at a time. Problem is I get an error from merging two dataframes.

Here's an error:

```
KeyError: "['avg'] not in index"
```

Here's my code:

```
df_features = pd.merge(max[['id', 'max']], variance[['id', 'var']], on='id', how='left')
df_features = pd.merge(df_features[['id', 'max', 'var']], df_avg[['id', 'avg']], on='id', how='left')
```

Any advice here?

Comment: can you print df_avg.columns?

Comment: We'll need to see your data....

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668788/pandas-joining-dataframes-with-different-index-levels-datetime  for merging dataframes with different index levels.

Comment: @jackotonye thanks! I'm trying to merge multiple dataframes and it's relevant article.

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue of wrong column name('avg' was not correctly defined above), but it merged successfully.